# Highlight the first entry and replace “quiet splash” with “nomodeset”-HOW DO I DO THAT?

Tags: grub2, plymouth, nomodeset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set nomodeset for installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation)

The guide is from here: http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/ubuntu-11-04-blank-screen-on-boot-solved/

can someone explain to me how do i do that?

Thanks! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction is:

> Reboot and keep your finger on the “SHIFT” key till you get the grub
>   menu. Highlight the first entry and replace “quiet splash” with
>   “nomodeset” .

So

- hold down the shift key when booting starts.
- You will then get a console mode menu. The top option should be selected. Press 'e' to edit that line.
- Scroll down to the "kernel..." line. The is the line that tells Grub which kernel to boot with and the parameters to be passed to the kernel when it boots are placed at the end of this line.
- Press 'e' again to edit this line.
- Move to the end of the line. Delete the text that says "quiet splash" and then enter "nomodeset" instead, ensuring there is a space between the new option and any other option.
- Once you have added the parameter to the end of the line, press Enter to accept the editing.
- Then press 'b' to boot using that kernel and those parameters.

(Instructions adapted from [this guide](http://grumpymole.blogspot.com/2007/05/ubuntu-how-to-edit-grub-boot-parameters.html).)