# Boot to black screen, nomodeset doesn't help

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, uefi

So, I just got a new lenovo Y510p with windows 8 on it by default. I had read up about UEFI and all that, and was ready to go when it arrived today. I first tried disabling UEFI so I could install 12.04 64 bit because I wanted a stable version. It was a black screen on the installer so I googled it and enabled nomodeset to fix the problem. 12.04 installed fine, but now when I try to boot normally its a black screen again. I assumed it was the same problem so I googled how to enable nomodeset outside of the installer. I found three methods people were saying, [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109944/highlight-the-first-entry-and-replace-quiet-splash-with-nomodeset-how-do-i-d) that says to replace quiet splash with nomodeset in GRUB, [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) which seems to say to replace quiet splash with nomodeset and link it with $vt_handoff with an underscore, and [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) which shows adding nomodeset to the end of the linux /boot line. All of these methods I tried on 12.04 and 13.04 (with UEFI reenabled) to no avail. However, on two of the methods I did get a list of checks showing if different things pass or fail on which the "generic graphic drivers" or something along those lines showed a fail. Anything I can do here??

Comment: I linked to that thread as a non-working solution I already tried.

Comment: If none of those work then unfortunately you need to file a bug.